# How to use containedIn with large array of pointer data type in parse server php

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-server

The plan table have user field, it is pointer type.
I am going to get plans using array of users.
Like this.

```
$users = $user_query->find(true);
$plans = $plan_query->containedIn('user', $users);
```

But `$users` is large, so I got the `bad request` error.

I've tried like following.

```
$users = $user_query->find(true);
$plans = $plan_query->containedIn('user', array_slice($users, 0, 50));
```

It was working well. But I need the plans for total users.
Is it possible?
Here is the document for parse server php.
https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `matchesQuery` function for this:

```php
$plan_query->matchesQuery('user', $user_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

In parse database query results are limited to 100. In the old Parse hosted backend, the maximum limit was 1,000, but Parse Server removed that constraint.So, if you want to get all of the users, you have to query few times and store the result in an array. After that you can use it.

$users = $user_query->find(true);

$plans[] = $plan_query->containedIn('user', array_slice($users, 0, 100));